# How to write this 301 rule in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have moved from a free blogging service to my own hosting. I don't have control full control over my old blog engine, but I can rewrite some links via theme creation facilities. That way, I plan to redirect my old users to my new site.

Links such as `http://oldomain.com/post/post_id` will be written as `http://newdomain.com/http://olddomain.com/post/post_id` because theming facilities doesn't allow me to get urls relative to root of site.

What I want to do is to redirect `http://newdomain.com/http://olddomain.com/post/post_id` to `http://newdomain.com/post/post_id` using a `.htaccess` file on my new domain.

How can I achieve this using a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+http://[^/]+([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.

Comment: Sure, I was just waiting for cooldown period to end.